# Inserting a TAB space into a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have seen few tutorials that claim to solve this issue online but they do not work. I would like to insert a TAB space when the TAB key is pressed, into my *multiline* TextBox.

A dudes response from Microsoft was that, by design, Metro apps will bring focus to the next control if you press TAB inside a TextBox. Now, this would make sense, if you were pressing TAB on a Single-line TextBox. But in a multiline TextBox? Don't you think it's more likely that the user will want to insert a TAB?

And yes, I know, you can insert a TAB space in a Metro TextBox by pressing Ctrl+TAB. But that is error prone, since most of us are used to just pressing TAB, and old habbits die hard sometimes.

Here is my issue. I have a text editor feature of my app where the user may need to enter large amounts of data. And you know what people are like, they like to separate things to make their text documents more readable and it's very uncomfortable and more tedious to use Ctrl+TAB. So I would like to know if anybody can help with a workaround for this (it can't involve a RichTextBox, though)?

Also, if I manage to find a workaround, will this increase the chances of my app release being rejected by the Store?

Comment: The reason you got the response you did is because it's standard behavior in plain text input fields for TAB to move you to the next field. Why is it that you cannot use a RichEditBox? When you want formatting as part of the input, that's the control to use.

Comment: Hello @devhammer, In WindowsForms and WPF Desktop apps you can press TAB and expect a TAB space in a plain text box. And that's what people are going to expect. And some people won't even think to try the Ctrl+TAB combo. That being said, the response I received was expected, and I don't have a problem with this new design choice by Microsoft, it's the fact that there are many people who are complaining to me about this and if they're complaining, then chances are that people who download my app from the store may complain about it, and there doesn't appear to be anything I can do for them.

Comment: Can't you just set the `AcceptsTab` property to `true`?

Comment: @AntonieBlom `AcceptsTab` does not exist for `TextBox` controls in Metro style applications.

Comment: @jAsOn That's a shame. Another reason to dislike metro!

Comment: @AntonieBlom For me, there are many reasons I hate Metro style apps, but I still use them because some of the features are just way too cool to ignore. I love the Share contracts, for example. The only things I dislike about Metro apps are some of the unnecessary limitations.

Comment: @jAsOn I just created a new Windows Forms app, and added two textbox controls. The only way that I could get them to accept tabs was to set the Multiline property to true, and set AcceptTabs to true. The default behavior (the point I was making) of a textbox control is to use tab to move from field to field. Same for WPF. You have to change the defaults to get the behavior you are after.

Comment: @devhammer My apologies, I must have misread your comment. Point taken.

Comment: @jAsOn Heh...no apologies necessary. I may not have been adequately clear. Looks like handling the TAB key in code is the way to get this done, so hopefully one of the solutions below will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the KeyPress event of your TextBox, capture the Tab key by inspecting the KeyCode of the pressed key, and then set the Handled property of the KeyEventArgs to true so the key isn't passed onto any other controls.

Use SendKeys to send a "Tab" character to the TextBox to mimic the behavior of pressing "Ctrl+Tab", like you said:

```
TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          SendKeys(^{TAB});
      }
}
```

The carrot (^) represents the CTRL key.

Comment: @jAsOn I'm glad you got it working and found my comments helpful! If you figured out this particular issue, please close the question by marking it answered, or update the question with an answer of your own if you solved it with your own ideas. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
richTextBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **KeyPress event** of your textbox control. Make sure that you have the property set true for multiline on the textbox control
This would work if you are using a RichText Control which is what I would suggest

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab) 
{
    e.Handled = true;
    string SelectionText = "";
    TextBox.Document.Selection.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, SelectionText);
    TextBox.Document.Selection.TypeText(char(9) + SelectionText);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @DJ K, KeyChar doesn't work in Metro apps. Their equiv. is: `if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab) { }`

Comment: jAsOn I didn't realize this was Metro App. I will change / alter my answer.. thanks for the keen eye

Comment: Sorry @DJ K, `AppendText` does not exist in `TextBox` controls for Metro style apps. I've tried a few other similar versions of this as well, like getting the current position of the Caret and then inserting a TAB space, then setting the Caret position to the end of that TAB space, but for some reason this does not work as expected.

Comment: Just saw your comment. No probs :)